# How to force stop the formating proccess of a Hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, format, diskpart

I have an issue with an hard drive (pretty slow) and I wanted to format it on windows using diskpart. As I was looking for options I pressed enter on the command line "format". It's been 12hours and I'm at 5%, increasing every 3-4 hours.. I tried rebooting, disconect power, cancel it throught disk manager, clean the disk, put it offline. non of this is working, now I just want a quick erase and get it over with.. How do I force stop the format process and put it back to RAW ??

Comment: I would assume removing the partitions and creating a new one would do it. But if formatting itself is really slow, it is possible the disk is dying.

Comment: Pull power--that hard drive really won't run without any power, and that PC will stop.  If a laptop, hold the power button down.  Take the battery out if necessary.  since you've got nothing whatsoever worthwhile on the HD anyway, you've got nothing to lose.

Comment: Disk is a 1To HDD and is dying. I agree on that but that's a laptop (not mine)  and can't afford to buy a new hdd. I have the system partition of 500Mb on it but I guess I can't really erase it.

Comment: Also, already took it out of any power (for about 30sec) is that enough ?

Comment: I managed to screw it out, I will format it from my own computer, might work !

Comment: You should be able to do a "Quick Format".  It should complete in a few seconds, maybe a minute.  However, it sounds like there are many bad sectors.  You will need to do a chkdsk /R on the disk, and that will probably take just as long.

Comment: Hi back, I did that, windows says it's all clean.. I didn't really trust it so I did a scan with cristaldisk, I have defectuous clusters and multiple sector damages (200) due to forced shutdown. nothing I can repair myself.
I finnaly found how to : unscrew your laptop and plug it in another computer THEN erase it ! It's all clear now !

Comment: For future users: If it is an external HDD, simply unplug it and reformat with a quick format. Also reassign drive letter if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Open task manager go to processes/details and kill vds.exe then go to services and start Virtual Disk - VSD 
You have to reopen diskpart to refresh disk/volumes